# ¿Como puedo mostrar las categorías de x productos, las cuales a su vez tienen hijos (subcategorias), y estos tambien tiene hijos?

Tags: java, android

necesito ayuda estoy realizando una app donde tengo que mostrar las categorías registradas, la cuales se dividen en 4 niveles; el primer nivel son las categorías principales (padres), el segundo son los hijos de los padres o categoria principales, el tercero son las subcategorias o hijos de las categorías de segundo nivel y por ultimo el cuarto que vienen siendo los hijos que tengan las subcategorias del tercer nivel.

intente hacerlo con una lista expandible pero solo llego hasta el segundo nivel no se como pasar de ahi, alguna idea??

Asi obtengo los datos

```
try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(ServerResponse);

    String returnState = jsonObject.getString("returnState");
    String returnData = jsonObject.getString("returnData");


    JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(returnData);

    Iterator<String> keys = mainObject.keys();
    while (keys.hasNext()) {
        // obtiene el nombre del objeto.
        String key = keys.next();
        Log.i("Parser", "objeto : " + key);
        JSONObject jsonObject1 = mainObject.getJSONObject(key);
        //obtiene valores dentro del objeto.
        cate.add(jsonObject1.getString("cate_name"));

        if (jsonObject1.has("child")) {

            JSONObject mainObject1 = new JSONObject(jsonObject1.getString("child"));
            Iterator<String> keys1 = mainObject1.keys();
            while (keys1.hasNext()) {
                // obtiene el nombre del objeto.
                String key1 = keys1.next();
                Log.i("Parser", "objeto : " + key1);
                JSONObject jsonObject2 = mainObject1.getJSONObject(key1);
                //obtiene valores dentro del objeto.
                chi1.add(jsonObject2.getString("cate_name"));

                if (jsonObject2.has("child")) {
                    JSONObject mainObject2 = new JSONObject(jsonObject2.getString("child"));
                    Iterator<String> keys2 = mainObject2.keys();
                    while (keys2.hasNext()) {
                        // obtiene el nombre del objeto.
                        String key2 = keys2.next();
                        Log.i("Parser", "objeto : " + key2);
                        JSONObject jsonObject3 = mainObject2.getJSONObject(key2);
                        //obtiene valores dentro del objeto.
                        chi2.add(jsonObject3.getString("cate_name"));

                    }
                }
            }


        }


    }

}
catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("Parser", e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Tienes ejemplo del JSON?

Comment: Ese es el json, solo me falta un iterator para poder llegar al nivel 4